# Text width changes with screen's width

Tags: html, css, text

How can I achieve such effect as when the width of screen changes, the string "Essem" changes their width?
I have the HTML:

```
<h1><span>Essem</span><br />bli.</h1>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the viewport-relative unit `vw`, for instance:

```
.my-text {
    font-size: 10vw; /* font will scale to 10 percent of the window's width */
}
```

Although that requires a bit of fiddling to find the right value for your text.
There are JavaScript libraries that take care of this for you: [FitText.js](http://fittextjs.com/), [SlabText](http://freqdec.github.io/slabText/).

See: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/